# Skip un-editable cells in Kendo grid naviagation using TAB in Angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, angular-directive

I can navigate through cells using TAB. But I want to skip focus in to un-editable cell. For example I want to focus to the next cell(next row ProductName cell) by skipping Description cell when I am on the Units cell.

Here is the stackblitz..

[Kendo grid navigation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5q9ny7)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [editable]="false" to mark the disabled the kendo-grid-columns and then adding the following code block to InCellTabDirective onKeydown(); in case the grid is editable false it will focus to the next editable cell.

```
if(!this.grid.isEditingCell())
{
   this.grid.focusNextCell(this.wrap);
}
```

Comment: I can't use [editable]="false" in the kendo-grid-columns. Because I already use it for other task.